# How to make a copy of $@?

Tags: bash

Why does the following only output 'b' and not 'b c'?
What's the best way to make it output 'b c' please?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
# The above is GNU bash, version 5.2.2(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0)
# installed using Homebrew on macos Monterey

test() {
    shift
    xx=("$@")
}
test a b c
echo $xx
```

PS: Apologies if this is a duplicate - I searched but there were 14,501 results. :-(

Comment: `xx` is an array, and the expansion `$xx` expands to the first argument (here `a`). Use the array expansion: `echo "${xx[@]}"`.

Comment: D'oh! Thank-you. I'd convinced myself it was the assignment that was going wrong, not the printing out later.